# How to Create Issue in Jira Service Desk using REST APIs

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am totally new to world of APIs, and trying to create an Issue/Ticket in Jira Service Desk using Jira API, but not able to achieve it even after multiple tries.
If someone has command/code how to create Issue/ticket in Jira Service Desk using bash shell/powershell/python, it will be of great help.

```
C:\Windows\system32>curl -D- -u user:password -X POST --data { "serviceDeskId": "10205", "requestTypeId": "10000", "requestFieldValues": { "summary": "Request JSD help via REST", "description": "Desc Request JSD help via REST" }  -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jjiraservicedeskurl/rest/api/2/issue/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: serviceDeskId
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 10205,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: requestTypeId
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 10000,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: requestFieldValues
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: summary
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Request JSD help via REST,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: description
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Desc Request JSD help via REST
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
HTTP/1.1 400
X-AREQUESTID: 1037x7716x1
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-ASEN: SEN-L15877282
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9B5B3DA5D899E1897DC909CC57D94F78; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=BK2L-I3HA-D24Q-1X7S_ba3e1671ccd8a2bafa38871b994d5387159243b6_lin; Path=/; Secure
X-ASESSIONID: 16z1cmb
X-AUSERNAME: mill_adv_user_test
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 07 Sep 2020 17:17:14 GMT
Connection: close

{"errorMessages":["Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@17a62b93; line: 1, column: 0])\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@17a62b93; line: 1, column: 3]"]}
C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: You payload object is invalid as far as json is concerned. Try using `{"serviceDeskId": "10205", "requestTypeId": "10000", "requestFieldValues": { "summary": "Request JSD help via REST", "description": "Desc Request JSD help via REST" }}`. Might be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for Pointing out @DebarghaRoy, found missing braces.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Input Data in a file data

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       { 
           "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "REST EXAMPLE",
       "description": "Creating an issue via REST API",
       "issuetype": {
           "name": "Incident"
       }
   }
}
```

Curl Command:

```
curl -D- -u user:password -X POST --data-binary "@data"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jiraservicedeskurl/rest/api/2/issue/
```